# How can I use/display an image in a plotlyjs axis tick label

Tags: plotly.js

When displaying the results of a survey as a bar chart, I want to display predefined images (think "thumb up", "thumb down", etc...) as labels of the choices (i.e. below each bar) instead of a text value.

Some HTML markup seems to be interpreted (e.g. `<i>`, `<b>`), but most HTML (such as `<img>`) is escaped.